# iphone support Screen media type then how to make PC website compatible with iphone screen?

Tags: iphone, css, xhtml

iphone support "Screen" media type then how to make PC website compatible with iphone screen? While both uses same media type?

I know iphone do not support FLASH but if website has fixed width images, uses of jquery and 960 px fixed width. then how to make compatible with small screen iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking has to do with the viewport meta tag. Try this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=220, user-scalable=yes" />
```

You might also try to adjust the width to best work with your website.  But at least this is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a separate stylesheet intended for the iPhone browser, and link to that stylesheet this way:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I've used this technique myself, and it is recommended in Apple's [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone/OptimizingforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006517-SW2). Older browsers will ignore the `only` keyword and won't read your stylesheet.

In that iPhone-specific stylesheet, try including some rules to scale your text and images, and show/hide content until the site displays nicely on the smaller screen.